# Import error with keras and theano

Tags: python, theano, keras

My keras works fine with theano and GPU, but this morning, after I upgrade keras and theano with:

```
pip install git+git://github.com/fchollet/keras.git --upgrade --no-deps
pip install git+git://github.com/Theano/Theano.git --upgrade --no-deps
```

and run `import theano`, it first raise an error of:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/__init__.py", line 79, in <module>
    from theano.scan_module import (scan, map, reduce, foldl, foldr, clone,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/scan_module/__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from theano.scan_module import scan_opt
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/scan_module/scan_opt.py", line 71, in <module>
    from theano.scan_module import scan_op
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/scan_module/scan_op.py", line 58, in <module>
    from six import iteritems, integer_types, raise_from
ImportError: cannot import name raise_from
```

then run `import theano` again, it raise the error of:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/__init__.py", line 79, in <module>
    from theano.scan_module import (scan, map, reduce, foldl, foldr, clone,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/scan_module/__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from theano.scan_module import scan_opt
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/scan_module/scan_opt.py", line 60, in <module>
    from theano import tensor, scalar
ImportError: cannot import name tensor
```

run `import keras`, it first raise an error of:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import backend
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/backend/__init__.py", line 66, in <module>
    from .theano_backend import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/backend/theano_backend.py", line 1, in <module>
    import theano
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/__init__.py", line 79, in <module>
    from theano.scan_module import (scan, map, reduce, foldl, foldr, clone,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/scan_module/__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from theano.scan_module import scan_opt
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/scan_module/scan_opt.py", line 71, in <module>
    from theano.scan_module import scan_op
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/scan_module/scan_op.py", line 58, in <module>
    from six import iteritems, integer_types, raise_from
ImportError: cannot import name raise_from
```

then run `import keras` again, it raise the error of:

```
Using Theano backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import backend
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/backend/__init__.py", line 66, in <module>
    from .theano_backend import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/backend/theano_backend.py", line 1, in <module>
    import theano
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/__init__.py", line 79, in <module>
    from theano.scan_module import (scan, map, reduce, foldl, foldr, clone,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/scan_module/__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from theano.scan_module import scan_opt
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/scan_module/scan_opt.py", line 60, in <module>
    from theano import tensor, scalar
ImportError: cannot import name tensor
```

I'm really puzzled about this problem, had anyone encountered this problem before? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

From the docs of `pip`

> --no-deps, --no-dependencies
>                           Ignore package dependencies

Remove that flag and everything should work

Comment: Thank you. I deleted --no-deps and run 'pip install git+git://github.com/Theano/Theano.git --upgrade' and 'pip install git+git://github.com/fchollet/keras.git --upgrade' again, but the error still exist as before

Comment: uninstall both of them, and run the install again....without `--no-deps` of course